# npx but use version in package json

Tags: npx

I have a build script in javascript project that uses parcel to iterate through folders and finding index files and then building those projects. When I find an index file I run this command:

`npx parcel build ${indexFilePath} --out-dir ${outDir} --target node`

But, if the person running this build script has not installed packages with `npm i` yet, the npx command will install the latest version of parcel-bundler, where --out-dir is now deprecated and breaking the entire script.

Here is what's going on, distilled:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npm i
$ npx parcel --version
1.12.4
$ rm -rf node_modules
$ npx parcel --version
2.0.0-beta.2
```

Is there any option for npx to use the version in the package.json file that is already in the project and install it to node_modules? Or do I just ingrate the install step into my build? It just seems overkill, since all I need to build is parcel.

Am I abusing npx by using it like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple issues exist in `npx` regarding this problem : [#199](https://github.com/zkat/npx/issues/199) & [#15](https://github.com/npm/npx/issues/15)

The only option I found so far was to parse & extract version from my package.json using `node` repl (which should be available in your case)

Something like this :

```
npx parcel@`node -p -e "require('./package.json').dependencies['parcel']"` --version
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll follow those issues. I ended up extracting version from package.json with `jq`, but I prefer this solution.